# How to Refresh (F5) and get another page with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my web application, I got a form on 2 different pages, `purchase1` and `purchase2`.

If a customer refreshes the page at `purchase2`, I want the location to be changed back to `purchase1`.

I haven't found a way to do so, I've tried to make a config like that:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/purchase2', '/purchase1');
}
```

But obviously, that way I can never get to `purchase2` page.

I need it to happen only on manual user Refresh.

Is there any way to do so? Some built-in Angular function that happens on Refresh?

Something like

```
$scope.onRefresh = function(){
   $location.path('/dashboard/purchase1');
}
```

Haven't found anything like it.

Comment: are you adverse to using jquery?

Comment: Umm, I'm unfamiliar to Jquery, I'm pretty much newbie with frontend developing, in my app I'm using js-html5-css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, if someone is interested, I fixed it like that:

In purchase1.js I've added this to the submit() function:

```
$rootscope.demographic=1;
```

In purchase2.js I've added this code to the controller:

```
var init = function(){
      if(angular.isUndefined($rootScope.demographic)){
           $location.path('/purchase1');    
      }

    };
    init();
```

It is working because Refresh(F5) completely restarting the application, therefore also resets the $rootscope and makes "Demographic" Undefined.

Upon entering purchase2, "init" function will start, if we came from purchase1 everything will be ok and demographic will be defined, otherwise we will just load purchase1 again.

:)

Answer (score 3):

You can listen for **beforeunload** event. **beforeunload** event will be triggered when someone hits a **F5** or refreshes the page anyhow. Do something like,

```
var windowElement = angular.element($window);
windowElement.on('beforeunload', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //below is the redirect part.
    $window.location.href = '/purchase1';
});
```

Put this code on **purchase2** page.

Comment: I've added $window in the module function, but still I refresh the page and stays in purchase2

Comment: There was error with $window undefiend, but I added it to the module function, still refreshing stays there

Comment: Note, `onbeforeunload` is called everytime page is unloaded i.e. *refresh, reroute, window closed* etc. Do check it before implementing it.

Comment: jQuery included? try including jQuery

Comment: Include jQuery before Angularjs. Include jQuery.js just before Including AngularJS.

Comment: Yes you can but for this you will need a `keypress` event on document. Also I'm not sure you will get *keyCodes* in `beforeUnload` event. Also, if user instead of `F5` clicks on refresh event, this check will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it.

Register a global listener for state change:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
    // If fromState is null that means it is a page refresh otherwise
    // The fromState will be the purchase1
    if (toState.name == 'purchase2' && !fromState) {
        $state.go('purchase1');
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
});
```

By global, I mean register the above in such a controller whose scope is available throughout your application like a controller added to your `body` or `html` tag.

Also, I'm assuming the `purchase1` & `purchase2` are the name of your states for both the pages. If they are parameters to a common state you can alter the code above.

Comment: rootScope could be the option for the global listening right?? Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

What happens on refresh is the same as what happens on first load.

What you can do is check whether the user has been here already, e.g. by setting a cookie and reading it later.

However, I think you should rethink your design. Why would you invest your time into making refresh function behave worse?

Comment: I know it's wierd, but I'm trying to avoid cookies with the application.
But now that you say that, perhaps I can use rootScope to check.

Answer (score 0):

I think, javascript isnt the right way because javascript does not know anything about the previous page, because it will be rendered when page is already loaded. So try to check this in your server side application like in php or jsp and read the request-header because there you can get current url and redirect user to the new url

Answer (score 0):

You can try to have a flag say *purchase2-loaded* and keep this variable in `localStorage`. You can then write an IIFE, which will check value of this variable and reroute to *purchase1*.

Also on *purchase1*, reset it to `false`.

Note:*This is a pure JS Code and relies on localStorage.*

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ng4ok8c9/).

#### Sample Code

```js
(function(){
  var isPurchase2Loaded = localStorage.getItem("Purchase2");
  if(isPurchase2Loaded || isPurchase2Loaded === undefined){
    document.write("Rerouting to purchase 1...");
  }
  else{
    document.write("Loading for the first Time...");
    localStorage.setItem("Purchase2", true);
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$state.go('purchase1');
```

this should resolve your problem.